# How to verify the actual data in Tensorflow slim dataset

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

I have encoded my data into tfrecord files. For each image, I encode multiple bounding boxes with multiple labels with it. Now, I want to verify whether my data have been correctly decoded by the Tensorflow/slim dataset type. I write a following test:

```
def test2(sess):
  labels_to_class = read_label_file(label_fname)
  reader = tf.TFRecordReader
  keys_to_features = {
    'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature(
      (), tf.string, default_value=''),
    'image/format': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value='jpg'),
    'image/object/labels': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
    'image/object/truns': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
    'image/object/occluds': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
    'image/object/bbox/xmin': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
    'image/object/bbox/xmax': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
    'image/object/bbox/ymin': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
    'image/object/bbox/ymax': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64),
  }
  items_to_handlers = {
    'image': slim.tfexample_decoder.Image('image/encoded', 'image/format'),
    'object/label': slim.tfexample_decoder.Tensor('image/object/labels'),
    'object/truncated': slim.tfexample_decoder.Tensor('image/object/truns'),
    'object/occluded': slim.tfexample_decoder.Tensor('image/object/occluds'),
    'object/bbox': slim.tfexample_decoder.BoundingBox(
        ['ymin', 'xmin', 'ymax', 'xmax'], 'image/object/bbox/'),
  }

  decoder = slim.tfexample_decoder.TFExampleDecoder(
    keys_to_features, items_to_handlers)

  dataset = slim.dataset.Dataset(
    data_sources=filename_queue,
    reader=reader,
    decoder=decoder,
    num_samples=sample_num,
    items_to_descriptions=_ITEMS_TO_DESCRIPTIONS,
    num_classes=_NUM_CLASSES,
    labels_to_names=labels_to_class)

  provider = slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(dataset)

  keys = provider._items_to_tensors.keys()

  print(provider._num_samples)
  for item in provider._items_to_tensors:
    print(item, provider._items_to_tensors[item])

  [image, label] = provider.get(['image', 'object/label'])

  print('AAA')

  sess.run([image, label])

  print('BBB')
```

When I run the above codes, it shows:

```
6
image Tensor("case/If_2/Merge:0", shape=(?, ?, 3), dtype=uint8)
object/label Tensor("SparseToDense:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int64)
object/occluded Tensor("SparseToDense_1:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int64)
record_key Tensor("parallel_read/common_queue_Dequeue:0", dtype=string)
object/bbox Tensor("transpose:0", shape=(?, 4), dtype=int64)
object/truncated Tensor("SparseToDense_2:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int64)
AAA
```

Then the program stops there forever without providing any error message. 
The program has shown the correct example number (6) and the correct types of the tensors I encoded, but I still want to check the values in the tensors.
Is there anyway that I can check their values?

Thank you for help.

-----------------Update--------------------

The codes I added are:

```
tf.train.start_queue_runners()

print('Start verification process..')

for i in range(provider._num_samples):
  [image, labelList, truncList, occList,
       boxList] = provider.get([
         'image', 'object/label', 'object/truncated',
         'object/occluded', 'object/bbox'])
  enc_image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(image)
  img, labels, truns, occluds, boxes = sess.run(
      [enc_image, labelList, truncList, occList, boxList])

  f = tf.gfile.FastGFile('out_%.2d.jpg' % i, 'wb')
  f.write(img)
  f.close()

  for j in range(labels.shape[0]):
    print('label=%d (%s), truc=%d, occluded=%d at [%d, %d, %d, %d]' % (
        labels[j], labels_to_class[labels[j]], truns[j], 
        occluds[j], boxes[j][0], boxes[j][1],
        boxes[j][2],  boxes[j][3]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to start queue runners for the image and label to be evaluated.

Comment: Would you please give me an example? I have googled online but none worked. Thank you.

Comment: Add tf.train.start_queue_runners() before calling any session.run

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, which works to validate the data. However, there is one problem. When I run my test program, the image reading orders are random every time, and may have duplicate. For example, when I make the validation for 6 records, one time the loaded image data are from item 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, and another time is from 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1. What may be the cause for this? Is there any way to limit one record only read once? Thank you.

Comment: pass shuffle=False to the dataset provider to remove randomization

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works well now. I see the previous shuffling=True was under epoch=None, indicating that I need infinite rounds of iterations to make all items sampling with the same time. When I set the epoch number, all items would be sampled with the same time.